# repeating elements in appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

I am trying to convert from the old web/appconfig.xml to appsettings.json.  The xml allows something like this

```
<Items>
   <Items name="x" qty = "1">
   <Items name="y" qty = "2">
</Items>
```

In appsettings.json, I want to do something similar.

```
"Items": {
   "Item": { "name": "x", "qty": "1"}
   "Item": { "name": "x", "qty": "1"}
}
```

The problem is the warning message "A member with the name "Item" already exists.  Is this warning a problem?  Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example JSON, you are attempting to assign to the property `Item` twice. `Items` is an object, and `Item` is a property of said object - it's not possible to have the same property *twice* for a given object.

A more JSON-friendly approach might be something like this:

```json
"Items": [
    { "name": "x", "qty": 1 },
    { "name": "y", "qty": 2 }
]
```

In this case, `Items` is an array with two objects. The individual objects could be modelled using the following C# class:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```

Using `IConfiguration`, there are multiple options for binding this. Here's one example:

```cs
var yourItems = someIConfigurationInstance.GetSection("Items").Get<Item[]>();
```

Comment: You read my mind on that last part. How would I be able to get the items out of the config without an identifier.

Comment: What do you mean by *without an identifier*? Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm new to .net core and still working through accessing configurations this way versus a web.config file where every single line has an identifier (probably not the right terminology).  I have some guides that I am using, but it didn't cover this case.